# Deny access domain administrator to my PC

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator, domain

My work PC is part of our company domain. If I understand it correctly this gives our domain administrator possibilities to alter or control some things, like forcing auto-update of Windows.

For several reasons, like access to domain resources, the PC needs to be connected to the domain (instead of a local workgroup). Eg. without doing this I can't let Windows Services run under a domain user (afaik).

As this PC is used for developing, I want to have full control over it, like (temporarily) not allowing updates.

Is it possible to deny all access to other (domain) users, like the domain administrator?

Comment: Unless you are an domain Administrator, this cannot be done, even if you are one it can be reversed by anyone else with that same permission. Furthermore its not **your** PC, so some helpful advice, don't do something the domain Administrator woudln't like.  **If you need Windows Update to be disable request they be disabled.**

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, a domain administrator always has **full access** to every machine on the domain (in a windows environment anyway). The domain administrator could grant your account **local administrator** access to the computer you use, and if your domain is **NOT** using **GPOs** (group policy objects) to enforce settings, then you will be able to change things like update behaviour.

The alternate is to (very nicely, always be nice to your admins) ask the domain administrator to **make GPO's not apply to your PC**, or apply only GPO's that don't interfere with settings you want to configure, or (if you're really really nice to him) get him to create you a custom GPO tailored to your needs.

But in answer to your main question: **No**, it is not possible to deny a domain administrator access to your PC, as that would circumvent exactly what domains are designed for, request that you be allowed to modify your PC's behaviour and hope that your domain administrator agrees.

Answer (score -1):

The way to circumvent this is to port your environment to an vm then you gain full control over domain administrator or at least with local system resources :-)